# OpenCV (Python) convert an image to a cv2.VideoCapture object

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to transform a static image (jpg) to a `cv2.VideoCapture` object. I can do a `cv2.imread` of the file to produce a `numpy` array, which is the same value i would get from doing a read on the capture object, and I know I can create an empty capture object by invoking the constructor without any arguments. Is there a way I can wedge the `cv2.imread` `numpy` object into the `cv2.VideoCapture` object in a way that the capture object will behave as a video capture with only one frame?

Comment: Just write your own class that provides the subset of `VdeoCapture` methods you need...

Comment: Simple example: https://pastebin.com/SLRMY73S -- what functionality do you actually need?

Comment: Thanks @Dan, I can see how that would work, but I was hoping to just reuse a VideoCapture object knowing it already has all the fields and methods I care about. Hopefully there's a way to do this easily, otherwise I will likely go this route.

Comment: `VideoCapture` is a C++ class exposed to Python. There is one backend that can read a sequence of single images (based on filenames), but it behaves like reading a video -- once all the frames were read, it's over and you have to reopen it. Unless you create a new VideoIO backend in C++ and integrate it with OpenCV, then my proposed solution is the best way to go forward IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Check if this is helpful

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("c:/fullpath/filename.png")
```

https://answers.opencv.org/question/317/how-to-read-directory-with-images-by-videocapture/

Comment: interesting idea but I tested it and it returns frame only once so it can't work in loop like video stream.